# how to get value from multiple table in oracle including date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables customers, orders and orderitems

#### Customer table

```
CUSTOMER#   LASTNAME    FIRSTNAME
1001    MORALES BONITA
1002    THOMPSON    RYAN
1003    SMITH   LEILA
1004    PIERSON THOMAS
1005    GIRARD  CINDY
1006    CRUZ    MESHIA
1007    GIANA   TAMMY
```

#### Orders table

```
ORDER#  CUSTOMER#   ORDERDATE
1000    1005    31/MAR/09
1001    1010    31/MAR/09
1002    1011    31/MAR/09
1003    1001    01/APR/09
1004    1020    01/APR/09
```

#### Orderitems table

```
ORDER#  ITEM#   ISBN    QUANTITY
1000    1   3437212490  1
1001    1   9247381001  1
1001    2   2491748320  1
1002    1   8843172113  2
1003    1   8843172113  1
1003    2   1059831198  1
```

I want to print the customer name and the total number of orders the customer has placed for all customer who have placed at least one order in march.

And i tried with the following query. i stucked on this problem. i am getting problem on adding the quantity for customer who have placed at least one order on march.

```
select c.firstname
, c.lastname
, or.orderitems# 
from customers c
, orderitems or
where customer# in 
(
    select customer# 
    from orders
    where order# in 
    (
        select order# 
        from orderitems 
        where /* (query truncated) */
```

Comment: Why do you need the Orderitems  table for this query?

Comment: to find the number of items

Comment: You say "I want to print the customer name and the total number of orders the customer has placed for all customer who have placed at least one order in march." So you need customers and orders, nothing more. Can you please post the needed result for that sample data?

Comment: its like:
Girard cindy has placed only one order on month of march so just print 1. if some other customer has placed order more that 1 item then all item must be added
    NAME                                     ITEM
1. Girrad Cindy                           1

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print the customer name and the total number of orders the customer has placed for all customer who have placed at least one order in march.

You do not need the `OrderItems` table for this.  So you can do:

```
select c.lastname, c.firstname, count(*)
from customers c join
     orders o
     on c.CUSTOMER# = o.CUSTOMER#
group by c.lastname, c.firstname
having sum(case when orderdate >= date '2009-03-01' and orderdate < date '2009-04-01'
                then 1 else 0
           end) > 0;
```

You can also filter before the aggregation, using `exists` (or `in`):

```
select c.lastname, c.firstname, count(*)
from customers c join
     orders o
     on c.CUSTOMER# = o.CUSTOMER#
where exists (select 1
              from orders o2
              where c.CUSTOMER# = o2.CUSTOMER# and
                    o2.orderdate >= date '2009-03-01' and
                    o2.orderdate <  date '2009-04-01'
             )
group by c.lastname, c.firstname
```

Although I like the `having` method, filtering before aggregation often performs better.

Comment: Altough the question is not that clear, the OP seems to need the sum of quantities, and not the number of orders, as stated in the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you may need something like this (assuming your date values have no time informations):

```
select LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, sum(QUANTITY)
from customers
       inner join Orders using(CUSTOMER#)
       inner join Orderitems using(ORDER#)  
group by LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
having count(
             case when ORDERDATE between date '2009-03-01'
                                     and date '2009-03-31'
                  then 1 
             end
            ) > 0
```

Here I apply an `having` condition to only get the customers having at least one order in march.
For example:

```
SQL> with customers(CUSTOMER#,   LASTNAME,    FIRSTNAME) as
  2  (
  3      select 1001, 'MORALES' , 'BONITA' from dual union all
  4      select 1002, 'THOMPSON', 'RYAN' from dual union all
  5      select 1003, 'SMITH'   , 'LEILA' from dual union all
  6      select 1004, 'PIERSON' , 'THOMAS' from dual union all
  7      select 1005, 'GIRARD'  , 'CINDY' from dual union all
  8      select 1006, 'CRUZ'    , 'MESHIA' from dual union all
  9      select 1007, 'GIANA'   , 'TAMMY' from dual
 10  ),
 11   Orders(ORDER#,  CUSTOMER#,   ORDERDATE) as
 12  (
 13      select 1000, 1005, to_date('31/MAR/09', 'DD/MON/YY') from dual union all
 14      select 1001, 1010, to_date('31/MAR/09', 'DD/MON/YY') from dual union all
 15      select 1002, 1011, to_date('31/MAR/09', 'DD/MON/YY') from dual union all
 16      select 1003, 1001, to_date('01/APR/09', 'DD/MON/YY') from dual union all
 17      select 1004, 1020, to_date('01/APR/09', 'DD/MON/YY') from dual
 18  ),
 19   Orderitems(ORDER#,  ITEM#,   ISBN,    QUANTITY) as
 20  (
 21      select 1000, 1, 3437212490, 1 from dual union all
 22      select 1001, 1, 9247381001, 1 from dual union all
 23      select 1001, 2, 2491748320, 1 from dual union all
 24      select 1002, 1, 8843172113, 2 from dual union all
 25      select 1003, 1, 8843172113, 1 from dual union all
 26      select 1003, 2, 1059831198, 1 from dual
 27  )
 28  select LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, sum(QUANTITY)
 29  from customers
 30         inner join Orders using(CUSTOMER#)
 31         inner join Orderitems using(ORDER#)
 32  group by LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME
 33  having count(case when ORDERDATE between date '2009-03-01' and date '2009-03-31' then 1 end) > 0;

LASTNAME FIRSTN SUM(QUANTITY)
-------- ------ -------------
GIRARD   CINDY              1

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
select c.FIRSTNAME , c.LASTNAME , count(i.quantity)
from Customer c , Orders o , Orderitems i
where c.CUSTOMER# = o.CUSTOMER#
and o.ORDER# = i.ORDER#
and o.ORDERDATE between '01-mar-2018' and '30-mar-2018'
group by c.FIRSTNAME , c.LASTNAME;
```

Comment: Nice answer; though your `group by` columns don't line up with your non-aggregate `select` atm (i.e. code isn't quite valid).

Comment: The `count` will count the occurrences, not sum the quantities. Using dates this way is dangerous and may not work. This gets the quantities of orders placed in march (up to 30...), but the OP seems to need the total of all orders, for users who placed an order in march. Besides, it would be better switching to  ANSI  join syntax.